# Transitive action on two sets!

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and G acts transitively on  sets $X$ and $Y$. Let $a$ and $b$ belongs to $X$ and $Y$ respectively and $G_{a}$  be stabilizer of $a$ in $X$ and $G_{b}$ be stabilizers of $b$ in $Y$.Let $G$$=$$G_{a}$.$G_{b}$ then show that $G$$=$$G_{x}$.$G_{y}$ $\forall x \in X$, $\forall y \in Y$

Edit:$G_{x}$  denotes stabilizer of $x$ in $X$ and $G_{y}$ denotes stabilizers of $y$ in $Y$

Comment: You are using $G$ twice for two different groups

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear. What do you mean by $G_aG_b$, and why have you called it $G$ as well? And what do you mean by $G_x$ and $G_y$? If you are looking for help, you should both clarify your question and tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @rogerl now does question make sense to you?Frankly speaking I don't have proper idea to start,looking for some hint

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint on how to break this problem up into smaller pieces.
Try to prove the following :

1. If $G$ acts transitively on a set, then any two point stabilizers are conjugate.
2. If $G = HK$ is the product of two subgroups, then $G = H^x K^y$ for any $x,y \in G$.

To prove the second fact, it helps to write $x$ and $y$ in the form $hk$, and use

3. If $G = HK$, then $HK = KH$.

Comment: I can get $H^kK^h\subseteq HK$ using $HK=KH$ but not sure how to get equality.

Comment: Since $HK = KH$, we can write $kh^{-1} = k_1 h_1$. Then $H^k K^h = k^{-1} H k h^{-1} K h = k^{-1} H h_1 k_1 K h$.